# Hide/Show Rows of a tble CSS using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code, which is intended to hide/show specific rows of a table according to a check box:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#activate").click(function(){ 
    if ($("#activate").prop('checked')){
        $(".hidden").css("display","");
        } else {
        $(".hidden").css("display","none");      
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="activate" checked>
See all rows
<br>
<br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Columna 1</th>
    <th>Columna 2</th>
    <th>Columna 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data1</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hidden">
    <td>Data2</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data3</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hidden">
    <td>Data4</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This works fine when i want to show all the rows first, but doesn´t when trying to show only the specific rows first (which is what i need).

I tried using toggleClass() method but the code doesnt work more than once, ¿is there any other option i can use with jquery?

Comment: You didn't give any fiddle link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just chain on a `.trigger('click')`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#activate").click(function(){ 
    if ($("#activate").prop('checked')){
        $(".hidden").css("display","");
        } else {
        $(".hidden").css("display","none");      
        }
    }).trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="activate" checked>
See all rows
<br>
<br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Columna 1</th>
    <th>Columna 2</th>
    <th>Columna 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data1</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hidden">
    <td>Data2</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Data3</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="hidden">
    <td>Data4</td>
    <td>Data</td>
    <td>Data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I guess OP has the code for hiding all the `tr`s. But he don't know how to do the same for individual rows.

Comment: what I want is exactly what j08691 has done, but without calling any click event (because I can see the rows being deleted when page is loading)